# Why is constant not automatically inherited?

Tags: perl

As we know `constant` in Perl is just `sub`,

but why are they not inherited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Methods* are inherited, *functions* are not. If you want to inherit the constant, you'll need to call it like a method.

```
$self->FOO
```

or

```
__PACAKAGE__->FOO
```

That said, you should be *importing* constants, not inheriting them.

Answer (score 11):

As the matter of fact, they are:

```
use strict; use warnings;

package Father;
use constant CONST => 1;

package Child;
use base 'Father';
sub new { bless {}, shift }

package main;
my $c = Child->new;
print $c->CONST;        # 1
print CONST();          # undefined subroutine
```